# How to recursively delete collection in firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I needed a way to quickly clear an entire firestore DB but couldn't find great documentation for how to do it. Eventually I found on stack overflow this answer ([Clear Firestore database of all data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53419891/clear-firestore-database-of-all-data)) but was a bit nervous about how long it would take to clear my entire DB of millions of documents, so I want a way to just recursively delete a collection at a time.

Background: I've been running some tests migrating large amounts of data from an old DB to firestore, and after each run I want a clean slate to work with in firestore. Do NOT use this on production data!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This is now documented via `recursiveDelete` function:

- https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Firestore.html#recursiveDelete

Note that this is a relatively new feature, so you need to make sure your Firebase libraries are updated.

```js
// Setup
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require("./files/my-file.json");
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});
const firestore = admin.firestore();

// Delete
const documentRef = firestore
      .collection("users")
      .doc("M3S2iPhsiu2ZQmOK8ZcC");
await firestore.recursiveDelete(documentRef);
```

Comment: WOW this is beautiful. I wish this question and answer could get pushed to the top of S.O. for deleting subcollections. I feel like 98% answers here still explain the overly cumbersome process of batch-deleting individual documents in subcollections. Worked fast and beautifully for me.

Comment: Even Firebase documentation still says you have to recursively traverse your documents/collections yourself.

Comment: Great answer! I'm glad I found this

Comment: @kgaid does `recursiveDelete` have any limit?

Comment: weird this is still not in the docs, but please make sure you upgrade your firebase admin sdk or else you won't have access to this

Answer (score 3):

I was able to do this by running the firestore cli delete command, specifying each collection by path. Make sure not to start the path with a leading slash, or it will think you are referring to a directory on your computer. Example of how to run:

```
firebase firestore:delete "path/to/collection" --recursive
```

The `firestore:delete` command is sort of documented here as well: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#delete_data_with_the_firebase_cli

**Update**
Please note that the command may fail after deleting about 20000 documents. I think it might be a limit it hits. I just re-run with the same collection path a few times to fully delete collections that are larger than 20k docs.

Comment: Your answer is really straightforward and useful! My preferred method now :)

Answer (score 1):

From the Fireship website : https://fireship.io/snippets/delete-firestore-collection/ there is 2 options to delete collections in firestore :

**Option 1 :**
You can manually delete a collection or subcollection from the Firebase Console OR by using the CLI :

`firebase firestore:delete path-to-delete`

**Option 2 :**

It is possible to interact with Firebase Tools from a Cloud Function. This works especially well with Callable functions because you most certainly want to enforce some form of user authorization.
First, obtain CI token to authenticate firebase tools.

```
cd functions
npm i firebase-tools -D

firebase login:ci
# your_token

firebase functions:config:set ci_token='your_token'
```

The function should validate the user has permission to run the operation. If allowed, it runs the CLI command recursively on the collection and its nested subcollections.

```
const project = process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT;
const token = functions.config().ci_token;

exports.deleteCollection = functions.runWith({ timeoutSeconds: 540})
  .https.onCall((data, context) => {

  const path = data.path;
  const allowed = context.auth.uid === path.split('/')[0]; // TODO your own logic

if (!allowed) {
  throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
    'permission-denied',
    'Hey, that is not cool buddy!'
  );
}

return firebase_tools.firestore
  .delete(path, {
    project,
    token,
    recursive: true,
    yes: true,
  })
  .then(() => ({ result: 'all done!' }));
});
```

Comment: This is specifically to run this command as an admin. The Firebase Console is very slow for deleting large collections so I would not recommend that. Cloud functions have runtime and resource limits so I would also not recommend them for very large collections.