# Does deleting a firestore document delete its subcollections?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

The documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data) says that it doesn't, but is this up to date?

Is this also true when you delete a collection through the GUI? And yes I am aware you can do it with cloud functions.

Comment: The link you provided basically answers all your queries, yes you can trust that its up to date.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the document you’ve mentioned is updated. And no, deleting a document in Firestore does not delete its subcollections. While deleting the document in Cloud Firestore, the subcollections won’t be deleted automatically. You have to delete them manually instead.

For deleting a whole collection/subcollection, retrieve all the documents within the collection/subcollection and delete them. For larger collections, delete the documents in smaller batches to avoid out-of-memory errors. Repeat the process until you've deleted the entire collection/subcollection.
The recommended approach to delete a collection in production is by using a [callable function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections) like you’ve mentioned in your question that you’re aware of it.

You can also delete the data with the help of the Firebase [Console](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/using-console#delete_data). Deleting a document from the Console deletes all of the nested data in that document, including any subcollections.

Also, you can delete documents and collections from [Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli) by using the command mentioned below.

> `firebase firestore:delete [options] <<path>>`

Comment: Then what happens to the subcollections of a document if I just delete the document? Will they move somewhere else? Or will they not be accessible anymore and just waste storage on the cloud?

Comment: @Cedric in case you're still wondering, they belong in an "orphan" state, they don't show up in queries but will continue to be visible in the console

Answer (score 2):

This post answer to this problem **How to recursively delete collection in firestore?** [How to recursively delete collection in firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66013255/how-to-recursively-delete-collection-in-firestore)

```
const db = admin.firestore()
const ref = db.collection(collectionId).doc(documentId)
await db.recursiveDelete(ref)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's accurate.

Deleting a document does not delete subcollections.

You will see an option to delete subcollections in the Firestore Emulator, but it's not possible in production.