# Firestore recursive delete doesnt work as expected

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have used the following code in a Map iteration (as i havent found how to achieve a batch recursive delete) :

```
await firebaseTools.firestore
  .delete(path, {
    project: process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT,
    recursive: true,
    yes: true,
    token: functions.config().fb.token
  }).then(() => {
    console.log(`path data  ${path} was recursively deleted`);
  });
```

with Path being `doc.ref.path`
But Documents of collection get deleted but not the subcollections which leads to all my collection documents to be as Non-existent ancestor documents (which will complicated things now for cleaning)

Why the recursive function doesnt work as expected?

Thanks

Comment: Does this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66013255) provide useful information to your issue? Additionally, this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49286764) can help; if you could share your database structure like shown in the post that would be greatly appreciated.