# Deleting a collection in Firestore - Flutter/Android

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I am new at flutter with firebase so if this feels like a question which has been answered in the docs or by other questions, I apologize!!

Now I am saving user data in firestore and when a user deletes their account, I want that to be deleted too but the Firestore docs says that the only way to delete a collection us:

> To delete an entire collection or subcollection in Cloud Firestore,
> retrieve all the documents within the collection or subcollection and delete them.

This is not recommended for native devs but I thought of an idea:

**So firestore overwrites new data against the old one, so if we set a new collection (user-root) which has a single doc with no fields and then delete it, it would be read/write effective as it just overwrites all of the preexisting data.**

I have not tried this idea out but if anyone has a better approach to delete collections in firestore, please write an answer!

**Reference Links:**

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#collections
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to "set a new collection".  You can only read, write, and query individual documents within a collection.

The advice you quoted here about deleting a collection is [absolutely true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47860812/deleting-all-documents-in-firestore-collection) - you must query, iterate, and delete each document individually.  There are no workarounds for this for web and mobile clients.

If you wish to add a backend to your app, you could [use the firebase-tools library in a callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections) to make this process easier, but that library still follows this process to delete all documents in a collection.

Comment: so I have users  start their collections at the root, and for each user there are 4 required documents which have many sub-collections and documents, so when I query those 4 docs, will I be reading all the sub-collections as well? because that would be too expensive for me in terms of the toal READ (s)?

Comment: No, queries are shallow and only read documents in the immediate collection.  You have to query subcollections separately if you want those documents also.

Comment: So if I don't query the sub-collections (to delete them), would they be deleted or move up to the root collection?

Comment: No, deletes are shallow too.  All of this stuff you can try and see for yourself how it works.